# How to move product-addto-links after box-to cart in product-options-bottom magento2?

Tags: magento2

i just wanna move 2 button after Add to Cart button like picture and code.
Anny idea ? Pls help me, thank a lot <3

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding the `catalog_product_view.xml` and by moving the addto block, by creating the following file in your custom module:
`view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.addto" destination="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, sir. It's working and i tried this, it's works too
<move element="product.info.addto" destination="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom"
            after="product.info.addtocart.additional" />